# python3: plot x in function of y

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to plot a curve graph with in abcisse temperature of patients and in y axes the pourcentage.
I did the code below, but i want to update it to get like the curve in the picture attached.
Please help me

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_2022 = df[df['year'] == 2022]
df_2023 = df[df['year'] == 2023]

total_patients_2022 = len(df_2022)
total_patients_2023 = len(df_2023)
percentage_2022 = (df_2022['Temperature'].value_counts() / total_patients_2022) * 100
percentage_2023 = (df_2023['Temperature'].value_counts() / total_patients_2023) * 100
percentage_2022 = percentage_2022.sort_index()
percentage_2023 = percentage_2023.sort_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(percentage_2022.index, percentage_2022.values, label='2022', linestyle='-', color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(percentage_2023.index, percentage_2023.values, label='2023', linestyle='--', color='green', linewidth=2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Expecting to have curve like density curve but pourcentage in y.

Example of data of my dataframe: Percentage of patients in 2022 for each temperature:

```
32.7     2.040816
34.5     2.040816
34.7     2.040816
34.8     4.081633
35.0     2.040816
35.1     2.040816
35.2     2.040816
35.3     6.122449
35.4     2.040816
35.5    16.326531
35.6     6.122449
35.7     2.040816
35.8     8.163265
35.9     6.122449
36.0    12.244898
36.1     2.040816
36.2     2.040816
36.4     2.040816
36.5     6.122449
36.7     4.081633
36.8     2.040816
36.9     4.081633
37.4     2.040816
Name: Temperature, dtype: float64
Percentage of patients in 2023 for each temperature:
34.3     2.040816
34.5     2.040816
34.7     2.040816
34.8     2.040816
34.9     2.040816
35.0     6.122449
35.1     2.040816
35.2     2.040816
35.3     4.081633
35.5     8.163265
35.6     2.040816
35.7     2.040816
35.8     2.040816
35.9     4.081633
36.0    10.204082
36.1     8.163265
36.2     6.122449
36.4     6.122449
36.5     8.163265
36.6     6.122449
36.8     6.122449
36.9     4.081633
37.2     2.040816

Name: Temperature, dtype: float64
```

I tried to plot density:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_2022 = df[df['year'] == 2022]
df_2023 = df[df['year'] == 2023]
sns.kdeplot(data=df_2022['Temperature'], label='2022', shade=True)
sns.kdeplot(data=df_2023['Temperature'], label='2023', shade=True)
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title('Density Plot of Temperature for 2022 and 2023')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You forgot `plt.show()`.

Answer (score -1):

The shows graph is generated using `seaborn`. Previously the function `sns.distplot` is now replaced with `.displot`. Complete example is available [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot).

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.displot(data = df, x = "temperature", hue = "year", kind = "kde")
```

The `kde` here is short for Kernel Density Plot.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Hobi but you code plot a density with density in y axis. what i want i having percentage iny axis.

Comment: @tamo007 what you've plotted is the "density" of the "temperature" column. The density plot of values ranges from [0, 1] based on factors like standard deviations, percentiles, etc.